# How to create a redirect to point to the user's id?

Tags: 7, redirection, path-aliases

I'd like to create a redirect so when the user hits `mydrupal.com/my-account` its redirected to `mydrupal.com/users/3`

I'm using Pathauto and I know I can go to `admin/config/search/path/add` to add the redirect but I can't get it to point to the user id as variable. For instance, in the `existing system path` option I thought I could add `users/[uid]` but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you not redirecting /my-account to /user ? It will lead to the user profile page, If he/she is logged in.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Do you want to add as an answer?

Comment: Let me add it so that the question will not be open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the `mydrupal.com/my-account` to particular user ID as `mydrupal.com/users/3`

You should redirect them to `mydrupal.com/user` which will lead them to thier profile page if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could also use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this.

Here is the rule you'd need for it (in Rules export format, just use copy/past to import it in your own setup):

```
{ "rules_redirect_an_old_path_to_a_new_path" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect an old path to a new path",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ],
          "match" : "the_old_path",
          "operation" : "starts"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Sorry, the old path (= /the_old_path) is no longer in use, you will be redirected automatically to its corresponding path (= /the_new_path)" } },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "the_new_path" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

A few more tweaks to make it fit your exact scenario:

- change all occurences of `the_old_path` to `my-account`.
- change all occurences of `the_new_path` to `user`.

Whenever such redirect actually happens, the user will also receive an informational message like so:

> *Sorry, the old path (= `/my-account`) is no longer in use, you will be redirected automatically to its corresponding path (= `/user`)*

If you don't want such message to appear, then just delete the line containing `drupal_message` in the exported rule above.

**Note**: No [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) involved using this approach, just [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).